# Populate MYSQL Column from specific rows in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL (using mySQL Community Workbench) and not sure where to begin with this problem.

Here is the overview: I have two tables in my `food` database: `branded_food` and `food_nutrient`

The important columns in `branded_food` are `fdc_id` and `kcals`.

The important columns in `food_nutrient` are `fdc_id`, `nutrient_id`, and `value`

`branded_food`'s `fdc_id` column indexes into `food_nutrient`'s `fdc_id` column. However, this returns every nutrient in the food, when I only want nutrient id `208`'s `value` entry.

Here is an example:

`branded_food` looks like:

```
fdc_id | kcals
-----------------
123    |  (Empty)
456    |  (Empty)
...    |  (Empty)
```

`food_nutrient` looks like:

```
fdc_id | nutrient_id | value
----------------------------
123    |  203        | 23
123    |  204        | 25
123    |  ...        | ...
123    |  208        | 500
```

Essentially, I would like to write some sort of loop that goes through each `fdc_id` in `branded_food`, finds the row in `food_nutrient` that has `fdc_id` equal to the looped value, and then populate the `kcals` in the row of the `fdc_id` in `branded_food`. Thus the first example row should populate like:

```
fdc_id | kcals
-----------------
123    |  500
```

As an update, I have looked at `INNER JOIN` and have created this:

```
SELECT food_nutrient.amount,food_branded_food.description, food_branded_food.fdc_id
FROM food_nutrient
INNER JOIN food_branded_food ON food_nutrient.fdc_id = food_branded_food.fdc_id 
WHERE food_nutrient.nutrient_id = 208
LIMIT 1;
```

This will correctly display the `kcals` of the `food_branded_food.description` (the name of the food) that has `fdc_id` of `food_branded_food.fdc_id`. I limit to 1 because the query takes very long. Is there a better way?

Update #2: Here is something I recently tried, but just spins forever:

```
UPDATE backup_branded_food bf
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT food_nutrient.fdc_id,food_nutrient.amount amt FROM food_nutrient WHERE food_nutrient.nutrient_id = 208
            ) mn ON bf.fdc_id = mn.fdc_id
SET bf.kcals = mn.amt
WHERE bf.kcals IS NULL;
```

Running explain:

[image: After running explain]

And `SHOW CREATE TABLE food_nutrient`

```
| food_nutrient | CREATE TABLE `food_nutrient` (
  `id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `fdc_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `nutrient_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_points` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `derivation_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `min` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `max` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `median` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `loq` text,
  `footnote` text,
  `min_year_acquired` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
```

Running `SHOW CREATE TABLE backup_branded_food` (I use a backup of branded food instead of the actual table)

```
| backup_branded_food | CREATE TABLE `backup_branded_food` (
  `fdc_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_type` text,
  `description` text,
  `food_category_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `publication_date` text,
  `brand_owner` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `brand_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `serving_size` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `serving_size_unit` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `kcals` double DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
```

Comment: you don't need a loop. Just use `UPDATE + JOIN` to copy from one table to a related row in the other table, and `WHERE` to restrict it to the nutrient ID that you want.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, I will look into this. I was not expecting someone to outright solve the problem, which is why my example is not as extensive as what I am doing. Thank you for the help!

Comment: How did `fdc_id=123` end up with `kcals=500` when your `food_nutrient` tables have multiple values with similar `fdc_id`? What is the condition?

Comment: @FanoFN `kcals` has a `nutrient_id` (from `food_nutrient` of `208`. I would like only the nutrient with id `208` to populate the table.

Comment: Aw man.. I just see that you've mentioned `208` in your question, how did I miss that? Anyway, on you current query attempt, show us the execution plan (run `EXPLAIN` on your query).  Also, it's probably best if you can run `SHOW CREATE TABLE food_nutrient` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE food_branded_food` then post the result into your question.

Comment: @FanoFN Done. I couldn't get a good copy paste of the `EXPLAIN`, so I unfortunately had to use an image. I also attached an `UPDATE` query attempt I did, but did not work (spun forever).

Comment: ok.. thanks.. this helps  a lot because I can immediately see that your tables do not have indexes and that's a high possibility as to why the query took so long to run. I'll see what I can do and post some suggestion shortly.

Comment: @FanoFN Thank you so much for the help. Not only did this lead to an answer, but it was very valuable for my learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Table Indexes**:
The table structure info obtained from `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` shows that both table don't have any indexes and/or primary key. This is probably why your query runs very slow. To quickly fix this issue, let's start by adding indexes on columns appear in `WHERE` and `ON` (in the `JOIN`):

```
ALTER TABLE food_nutrient 
      ADD INDEX fdc_id(fdc_id), 
      ADD INDEX nutrient_id(nutrient_id);

ALTER TABLE branded_food 
      ADD INDEX fdc_id(fdc_id);
```

With these indexes added, the `EXPLAIN` shows the following:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | fn |  | ref | fdc_id,nutrient_id | nutrient_id | 9 | const | 1 | 100.00 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | bf |  | ref | fdc_id | fdc_id | 9 | db_40606077.fn.fdc_id | 1 | 100.00 |  |

Since I don't know the size of the table, I can't really test how quick the query will be after adding these indexes but I assume that this will improve the query speed significantly.

P/S: Normally, you would have at least 1 column assigned as `PRIMARY KEY` - which will never have any duplicates. In your table `food_nutrient`, there's an `id` column that might be the `PRIMARY KEY` but there's a possible unique combination between `fdc_id` and `nutrient_id`. Therefore, you might consider adding `UNIQUE KEY` on those two columns apart from adding `PRIMARY KEY` on `id`. [24.6.1 Partitioning Keys, Primary Keys, and Unique Keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html)

**Usage of aliases**:
This is to help make your query more readable. You didn't use any in your current query so you end up appending the full table name on column(s) that you're using in you operations:

```
....
FROM food_nutrient AS fn 
INNER JOIN food_branded_food fbf /*can simply be written without "..AS.."*/
ON fn.fdc_id = fbf.fdc_id /*the operation afterwards didn't require you to append full table name*/
...
```

Similarly, once you've added the table alias, you can use it in `SELECT` too:

```
SELECT fn.amount, fbf.description, 
       fbf.fdc_id AS 'FBF_id' 
          /*you can also assign a custom/desired alias to your column - as your output column name*/
...
```

Couldn't find official documentation on MySQL website but [here's a further explanation from a different site](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/alias.php).

**Alternative UPDATE syntax**:
Your current `UPDATE` query should be able to perform what you need but you probably don't need the subquery at all. This `UPDATE` query should work as well:

```
UPDATE branded_food bf 
 JOIN food_nutrient fn ON bf.fdc_id = fn.fdc_id
 SET bf.kcals = fn.amount 
WHERE fn.nutrient_id = 208
AND bf.kcals IS NULL;
```

[Here's a demo fiddle for reference](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=75167322bc00a505a79564a9a61d80ca)

Answer (score 1):

A `UPDATE` and an `INNER JOIN` gets you your wanted result

```
UPDATE branded_food  bf
INNER JOIN (SELECT fdc_id , SUM(value) svalue FROM Mfood_nutrient ) mn ON bg.fdc_id = mn.fdc_id
SET bf.value = mn.svalue
WHERE bf.value IS NULL;
```